# How does the informativeness of eigenfunction approximations relate to the accuracy of the solution?

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations, information-theory, approximation-theory

Consider the linear eigenvalue problem
$$ \hat{M} f = \lambda f, $$
where $\hat{M}$ is a linear operator with eigenfunction $f$ and corresponding eigenvalue $\lambda$. The algorithmic complexity of finding an exact solution scales exponentially with some complexity metric $\epsilon$.
Suppose an approximate solution is obtained through an algorithm with polynomial scaling, i.e.,  $\mathcal{O}(\epsilon^p)$. This algorithm involves solving the auxiliary problem
$$ \tilde{\hat{M}} \tilde{f} = \tilde{\lambda} \tilde{f}, $$
where $\tilde{\hat{M}}$ is a truncated version of $\hat{M}$ or $\tilde{f}$ is a constrained ansatz.

(a) Can it be demonstrated that there is no information contained in $\tilde{f}$ alone about the accuracy of the approximation, i.e., $\lambda - \tilde{\lambda}$ cannot be estimated by a function solely dependent on the parameters of $\tilde{f}$?

(b) Is it possible to establish that any useful metric providing insights about the error will require a computational effort scaling at least as $\mathcal{O}(\epsilon^q)$ with $q>p$?

I appreciate any insights, proofs, or references that shed light on the theoretical aspects of these questions.